# Firebase data normalized. How should I fetch a collection based on this structure?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularjs-service, angularfire

I think I am getting close, I am able to print out the ID of books belonging to a user but have been trying unsuccessfully to fetch the list of books belonging to a user, from the firebase books reference.

I'm following loosely the tutorial here:
http://www.thinkster.io/pick/eHPCs7s87O/angularjs-tutorial-learn-to-rapidly-build-real-time-web-apps-with-firebase#item-526e9330d90f99661f00046c

and also reading the documentation about denormalizing data here:
https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-04-12-denormalizing-is-normal.html

How should I go about it if I want to display the user in a page, followed by all its books?

#### firebase structure

```
FB
|
--user
| |
| --user1
|   |
|   --name: "test name"
|   --email: "test@test.com"
|   --books
|     |
|     "-JFZG3coHOAblHZ7XSjK": true
|     "-KJKJASDIUOPIWE9WEeJ": true
|     "-YtUTRGJLNL876F3SSwS": true
|
--books
  |
  --"-JFZG3coHOAblHZ7XSjK"
  | |
  | --title: "book title 1"
  | --ownerId: "user1"
  |
  --"-KJKJASDIUOPIWE9WEeJ"
  |  |
  |  --title: "book title 2"
  |  --ownerId: "user1" 
  |    
  --"-YtUTRGJLNL876F3SSwS"
  |  |
  |  --title: "book title 2"
  |  --ownerId: "user1"
```

#### View

```
<div data-ng-controller="UsersController" data-ng-init="findOneUser()">
  <h2>Profile</h2>
  <img class="image_preview" data-ng-src="{{user.photoUrl}}">
  <p>Name: {{ user.name }}</p>
  <p>Name: {{ user.email }}</p>
  <a data-ng-href="#/users/{{ userId }}/edit">Edit</a>

  <h2>Coffee Blends</h2>

  <div data-ng-repeat="book in user.books">
    <p>---</p>
    <p>{{user.books}}</p>
  </div>
  <!--<div data-ng-controller="BooksController" data-init="">-->

  <!--</div>-->
</div>
```

#### Controller

```
'use strict';

angular.module('ccApp.controllers.users', ['ccApp.services.users'])
    .controller('UsersController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$location', 'angularFire', 'Users',
      function($scope, $routeParams, $location, angularFire, Users){

      $scope.user = {};
      $scope.userId = $routeParams.userId;

      $scope.findOneUser = function(userId){
        if (!!$scope.userId){
          angularFire(Users.find($routeParams.userId), $scope, 'user');
        }
      };

      $scope.updatePhotoUrl = function(url, user){
        $scope.fileUrl = url;
        console.log($scope.fileUrl[0].url);
        user.photoUrl = $scope.fileUrl[0].url;
      };

      $scope.findUsers = function(){
        $scope.users = Users.collection();
      };

      $scope.findWholesalers = function(){
        $scope.wholesalers = Users.collection();
      };

    }]);
```

#### Service

```
'use strict';

angular.module('ccApp.services.users', ['ccApp.services.firebaseRefs'])
  .factory('Users', ['angularFireCollection', 'FireRef',
    function(angularFireCollection, FireRef){
      return{
        collection: function(cb){
          return angularFireCollection(FireRef.users(), cb);
        }
      , find: function(userId){
          return FireRef.users().child('/'+userId);
        }
      };
  }]);
```

Comment: What version of angularFire are you using? And why not 0.6? Also, what does Users.find return? A Firebase ref? A string?

Comment: @Kato AngularFire 0.3. I thought I'd play around with what's in the tutorial before changing around the libraries and potentially breaking some stuff.

  Users.find returns and binds the user data for the userId specified in the $routeParams, so I am quite certain its a firebase reference?

  This is the output of the call, Object {then: function, catch: function, finally: function}

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Begin by updating to angularFire 0.6. This looks 0.3.*ish. angularFire has been changed to `$firebase` and has a much more powerful and simplified interface.

**Vanilla Firebase**

I'll do this the hard way first as I think there is great value in understanding the underlying principle here. It's fairly complex, and I'll only cover the essentials. There are a lot of tiny edge cases to be handled as well:

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('UsersController', function($scope, $firebase, $timeout, $routeParams){
      var userId = $routeParams.userId;
      $scope.user = $firebase(new Firebase('URL/user/'+userId));

      // or, for 3-way binding and automatic writes back to Firebase
      var userRef = $firebase(new Firebase('URL/users/'+userId)).$bind($scope. 'user');

      // grab this users' books using Firebase (the hard way)
      $scope.books = {};
      var booksRef = new Firebase('URL/books/');

      // fetch the user's book list dynamically because it may change in real-time
      var indexRef = new Firebase('URL/user/'+userId+'/books');

      // watch the index for add events
      indexRef.on('child_added', function(indexSnap) {
         // fetch the book and put it into our list
         var bookId = indexSnap.name();
         booksRef.child(bookId).on('value', function(bookSnap) {
            // trigger $digest/$apply so Angular syncs the DOM
            $timeout(function() {
               if( snap.val() === null ) {
                  // the book was deleted
                  delete $scope.books[bookId];
               }
               else {
                  $scope.books[bookId] = snap.val();
               }
            });
         });
      });

      // watch the index for remove events
      indexRef.on('child_removed', function(snap) {
         // trigger $digest/$apply so Angular updates the DOM
         $timeout(function(snap) {
            delete $scope.books[snap.name()];
         });
      });
});
```

Then the HTML (this will be the same for the other examples below):

```
<div data-ng-repeat="(bookId, book) in books">
   {{bookId}}: {{book.title}}
</div>
```

Some of the edge cases not fully covered here:

- data is not sorted by priority ordering
- when a record is deleted from index, should call off() on data paths
- changes in ordering of the index won't change order of data records
- value of the index is not stored anywhere for reference (if it matters)

**FirebaseIndex**

[FirebaseIndex](https://github.com/Zenovations/FirebaseIndex) is a simple utility that takes an index like your book list and manages the code we just created above in a bit more sophisticated manner.

Unfortunately, FirebaseIndex doesn't support `value` events, so it can't be used with angularFire after 0.5.0 because of a change to angularFire's internal loading mechanisms. So it's not quite as short and sweet as it used to be.

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('UsersController', function($scope, $firebase, $timeout){
   var userId = $routeParams.userId;
   $scope.user = $firebase(new Firebase('URL/user/'+userId));

   var fb = new Firebase(URL);
   var index = new FirebaseIndex( fb.child('user/'+userId+'/books') );
   $scope.books = {};

   // almost magic
   index.on('child_added', function(snap) {
      $timeout(function() { $scope.books[snap.name()] = snap.val(); });
   });

   index.on('child_removed', function(snap) {
      $timeout(function() { delete $scope.books[snap.name()]; });
   });
});
```

**Firebase.util.join**

[Firebase-util](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-util) is a much more powerful and sophisticated library for normalizing paths. Because it returns an object that works just like a regular Firebase reference, it can also be used seamlessly with angularFire 0.5 and above.

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('UsersController', function($scope, $firebase){
   var userId = $routeParams.userId;
   $scope.user = $firebase(new Firebase('URL/user/'+userId)); 

   var fb = new Firebase(URL);
   var ref = new Firebase.util.intersection( fb.child('user/'+userId+'/books'), fb.child('books') );

   // magic!
   $scope.books = $firebase(ref);
});
```

Comment: Wow the regular method works PERFECTLY! It's much appreciated that you've shown the regular method just so the principle is understood. You know what they say about teaching a man to fish! I'll take a look at the other libraries now.

Comment: Best practice wise, do those code belong in the controller, or the service?

Comment: Controller is fine for learning and simple use cases. Move the code out to a service when it will be shared between controllers or when the controller gets long.

Comment: [angularFire-seed](https://github.com/firebase/angularFire-seed) has some interesting factories/services for [abstracting Firebase and angularFire](https://github.com/firebase/angularFire-seed/blob/master/app/js/service.firebase.js). This is a wonderful example of where to use a factory as it abstracts references to `Firebase` and your namespace URL to a single point. You can see how it [simplifies controllers](https://github.com/firebase/angularFire-seed/blob/master/app/js/controllers.js#L15)

Comment: @Kato omg, this is what i'm looking. Ok, Firebase.util.join vs vanilla firebase. which you recommended kato?

Comment: i think i prefer vanilla

Comment: I'm trying to use your Firebase.util example to create indexed objects. When I do the following, an entry is created in `books`, but not a matching index under `users/$userId`.  `$scope.books.$add( { name: 'Green Eggs and Ham', ownerId: userId } )`.  Am I using this right?

Comment: This seems extremely convoluted. I get the hierarchical / de-normalise  argument but why isn't there a better/easier way of querying your data?

Comment: @Greg because it's not a SQL database? If you want lightning-fast real time, scalable to millions of users, use Firebase; if you want slow but simple queries, and a huge IT team, use SQL or Mongo? Hint: Firebase will be adding more magical query-like capabilities in the near future so it can be both.

Comment: I had no idea there was a 0.6.0 angularFire, have been using an older version!

Comment: There is now a 0.7.1 release :)

Comment: @Kato Does `Firebase.util.intersection v0.8.0` implement the intersection as you described in the Vanilla Firebase example? I'm having issues depending on my security rules. If I make the entire resource list readable (e.g. `"books": { ".read": "auth != null" }`), the intersection works. However, if I use security rules per resource it doesn't work with `PERMISSION_DENIED` (e.g. `"books": { "$bookId": { ".read": ".read": "auth != null && data.child('ownerId').val() == auth.uid" } }`). It seems like intersection might be listing `/user/XXX/books` and `/books`, rather than querying each idxd ref

Comment: That's correct. Intersection retrieves both lists and then takes the intersection of them. I'll look for improvements during our next iteration, but for now it's a limitation.

Comment: I'm thinking two decent workarounds are: (1) Split the shared books into `public` and `private` parts, where `public` is the stuff you'd want to show in a list but don't mind if anyone can see it, and `private` is used for the details/edit drill-down with higher security. You would use `intersection` on `public`, but not on `private`. (2) Manually iterate the user's indexed list of books, and retrieve each referenced book directly (O(n) calls calls :/)

Comment: I believe `Firebase.util.intersection` does not exist anymore and is replaced by `Firebase.util.NormalizedCollection`.