# Drafts & Publishing in Firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase

Building a CMS and trying to find out the best way to handle drafts with Firebase. For example, site administrators will edit documents, which get published publicly to the site.

At first it seemed the perfect solution was to have a "public" property set to true and enforce it via a Security Rule as follows:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "documents": {
      "$id": {
        ".read": "data.child('public').val() == true"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

(as documented here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/rule-expressions/data.html)

but apparently that documentation is flawed because in that example I can hit /documents and it will give me all documents regardless of 'public' == true. To prevent that you have to change it to:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "documents": {
      ".read": false,
      "$id": {
        ".read": "data.child('public').val() == true"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Ideally I'd be able to expose a simple REST API endpoint for /documents/ that simply returned all the public documents with all their child properties.

Apparently Firebase doesn't support filtering (which is essentially what I was trying to do by saying "SELECT * FROM documents WHERE public = true".

So I see two options:

OPTION 1: Keep the REST API endpoint nice & clean by storing document drafts in a different place (like /drafts/documents). Administrators would create & edit draft documents with auto-save and then have a "publish" button that when clicked would COPY the current drafts to the public /documents.

OPTION 2: Not have the clean REST API endpoint of /documents and instead have /documentIndex which simply returns a list of document ids. Then the client would have to iterate through each documentIndex to call each individual document endpoint at /documents/:id. I worry about performance with this option. This option seems to be documented here: [Firebase data normalized. How should I fetch a collection based on this structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21721460/firebase-data-normalized-how-should-i-fetch-a-collection-based-on-this-structur?lq=1) but doesn't cover the implications to the REST API. I'm using AngularJS but other client's might want to consume the document data in other ways (hence why I want to expose the data via the REST API as well).

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Both approaches are good ones. An index is more flexible when the structure and ordering will change often or when multiple ordering possibilities exist (e.g. a list that is sometimes ordered by date and sometimes by rank). Additional listeners don't really have much affect on performance (it's generally not much more than the time required to fetch the bytes).

Moving data between paths, a sort of queue or folder approach, may work well for your needs, since you've emphasized REST access. If, unlike your specific use case, one wanted to move large amounts of data in bulk (several hundred megs) then this would not be a great approach since it requires downloaded the data to the client before writing it back to a new path.

If your goal is to optimize for the possible other clients then you're going to need to start by determining what those are and how they will be connecting. It's difficult to make any intelligent decision based purely on possibilities.

Before bothering with any optimizations purely for REST, I'd first try a bit of profiling to see how it performs. You may find this is plenty sufficient for the use cases you have in mind.