# Fetching denormalized data with firebase, angularFire

Tags: firebase, angularfire, firebasesimplelogin, denormalized

I'm trying to fetch all flowers data which belongs to a certain user, in this case simplelogin:69.

I'm starting with fetching all flower keys from the user, like this:

```
/users/simplelogin:69/flowers/

var ref = new Firebase("https://URL.firebaseio.com/users/"+uid+"/flowers");
var sync = $firebase(ref);
```

Now im stuck figuring out a clean way to fetch all the flower data by looping thrue every flower key from simplelogin:69 without looping thrue EVERY key in /flowers/  (in example below i only have three flower keys but in production i might have 10k).

I tried FirebaseIndex and firebase-util, but can't get it to work properly. Do anyone have any tips or anything? I've read previous posts here on stack but most seems out of date or not really suited for what im going for. Would really appriciate anything that can be solved with AngularFire.

Kind regards,
Elias

```
{
  "flowers" : {
    "-JiU57sFAfQwYtIq-LCl" : {
      "image" : "test",
      "name" : "test",
      "type" : "Roses",
      "uid" : "simplelogin:69"
    },
    "-JiU9-3ajlnFLpyUmBvL" : {
      "image" : "dasdasd",
      "name" : "sadasdas",
      "type" : "Roses",
      "uid" : "simplelogin:69"
    },
    "-JiUF-mioK3jQCYy6ZiG" : {
      "image" : "ss",
      "name" : "ss",
      "type" : "Lilies",
      "uid" : "simplelogin:69"
    }
  },
  "users" : {
    "simplelogin:69" : {
      "flowers" : {
        "-JiU57sFAfQwYtIq-LCl" : true,
        "-JiU9-3ajlnFLpyUmBvL" : true,
        "-JiUF-mioK3jQCYy6ZiG" : true
      }
    },
    "simplelogin:70" : {

    },
    "simplelogin:71" : {

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your data structure looks OK to me.  To get flower information for simplelogin:69, you would make one request for the users flower keys at `users/simplelogin:69/flowers`, then 3 requests to each of the flower data nodes under `flowers/{id}`.  That is 3 for 3 in this sample, but would be only 3 for 10K as you describe your production dataset.  I've struggled with this concept in Firebase, since Computer Science math is [0, 1, n], and the notion of doing 4 lookups seems totally fubar, but it can work out just fine in practice.  How many flowers will typical users have?

Comment: Thanks for the respons @JamesWing I believe a typical user will have about 100-200 flowers each, do you know a clean way to make multiple requests to different nodes with angularFire and making it bind to changes in firebase (for example if a user ads another flower, it will fetch that aswell).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it to work now, thanks to @Kato 's answer on thread:
[Firebase data normalized. How should I fetch a collection based on this structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21721460/firebase-data-normalized-how-should-i-fetch-a-collection-based-on-this-structur) (tried it before creating this thread but didnt get it to work, so made som small changes and now it works).

Posting the solution for anyone stubling upon the same situation:

```
$scope.flowers = {};

var flowerRef = new Firebase('https://URL.firebaseio.com/flowers/');
var keyRef = new Firebase('https://URL.firebaseio.com/users/'+checkAuth.auth.uid+'/flowers');

keyRef.on('child_added', function(snap) {
    var flowerId = snap.key();
    flowerRef.child(flowerId).on('value', function(snap) {
        $timeout(function() {
           if( snap.val() === null ) {
              delete $scope.flowers[flowerId];
           }
           else {
              $scope.flowers[flowerId] = snap.val();
           }
        });
    });
});

keyRef.on('child_removed', function(snap) {
    var flowerId = snap.key();
    $timeout(function(snap) {
        delete $scope.flowers[flowerId];
    });
});
```

Comment: Looks great, Elias. You could make this more elegant using $extendFactory, which would allow you to hook into the added/changed methods and download the flowers on the fly. I also [demonstrated this technique here](http://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/vspo65qm/). Note how `$$added` and `$$updated` fetch the user based on an id.

Comment: Thanks for the respons @Kato :) I will check out $extendFactory, appreciate the demostration link aswell.

Answer (score 0):

This really is a tough issue with Firebase.  If you implement a [custom factory object](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-extending-the-factories-firebasearrayextendfactory) for the user's flower list, you could dynamically request new flower data as the list changes.